# Open .csv file with Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, csv

I'm having a problem with this piece of my code in VBA and I can't figure out why it isn't working! I've tried another code to see if it was the loop that has the issue but the issue is specifically opening the files and not iterating through them.

```
Sub fileloop(Path)
Dim strFile As String, strPath As String
Dim MyBook As Workbook

strPath = Path '& "\*.csv"
strFile = Dir(strPath & "\*.csv")

MsgBox (strFile)

While strFile <> ""

'placed another messagebox here to see if the strFile was the same inside the loop.
MsgBox (strFile)

'this line has the error.   
    Workbooks.OpenText FileName:=strFile, _
DataType:=xlDelimited, Comma:=True, Local:=True

  set MyBook = ActiveWorkbook

    Call SortColumnB(MyBook)

    strFile = Dir

 Wend

End Sub
```

The error message I get goes something like this:

> 'AC000W0009.csv' could not be found. Check the spelling of the file name, and verify that the file location is correct.
>
> If you are trying to open the file from your list of most recently used files, make sure that the file has not been renamed, moved, or deleted.

I've tried so many variations apart from the one listed above and I can't understand why VBA won't recognize that the file exists.

**EDIT**

Going off of what Mike said about opening a file with the complete path the changes I made to the code to let it open .csv files:

```
 strPath = Path & "\"
strFile = Dir(strPath & "*.csv")



While strFile <> ""
MsgBox (strFile)                 'added path to file name.
    Workbooks.OpenText FileName:=strPath & strFile, _
DataType:=xlDelimited, Comma:=True, Local:=True
```

Comment: Place the **MsgBox** below the **While** to be able to view all the attempted *Opens*

Comment: Or at least add some `Debug.Print "..."` if you don't want pop-ups, it will help you find what's going wrong and you will keep a trace (You need the exec zone open in the editor)

Comment: Sounds like you need to add the path to the filename

Comment: Does `Debug.Print` work for every error within a subroutine if I put it at the start of the sub? Or does it just work on that specific error line? Sorry I've never used it before I usually just have the popups come up.

Comment: @Mike this is probably a silly question, but isn't `Dir`a way of finding files in a path specified and with the appropriate extension? Maybe vba is just not recognizing the path. I'll go ahead and see if adding the path in helps as well

Comment: @Mike I took out `Dir` and just had the path and file and it worked perfectly thank you so much! I don't quite understand why it needed the full path, but thank you.

Comment: @ella I beleve the DIR only returns the filename.  If you want to open it, you need to add the path back in.  http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/dir.php

Comment: @Mike gotcha. So If for example I wanted to delete all files with `.csv` then it would work with `Dir` but if I wanted to open them (like in my case) I need to have the full file path. Makes sense thanks. You can make that the answer I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I beleve the Dir only returns only the filename.

If you want to open it, you need to add the path to the file name returned by Dir.

There's some good examples [here](http://techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/dir.php)