# VBA to find all CSV files in a Variable Folder name

Tags: vba, excel, csv

I have a project to create VBA to find and open all CSV files in a folder that is named the current month.  I found some stuff online that seemed close but not quite.  They will eventually be converted to XLSX files and parsed. That part I have.  The macro that converts, parses and saves will be housed in a different file along the same path but not as "deep".

So on my Desktop is a folder name "CSV find  test".  Inside are two folders "Feburary" and "March".  I need it to open all csv files in the most recent month.  I have the rest of the syntax. . . . .

I wouldn't imagine that it would take a huge amount of syntax.  Thanks for any direction.

```
Sub OpenFile()

    FileMonth = Month(Date)
    FileDate = Format(Date, "mmmm")
    FilePath = "C:\Users\Me\Desktop\CSV find convert tests\" & FileMonth & "\" & FileDate & ".xls"

    Workbooks.Open Filename:="FilePath" <- - -  - error happens here.

End Sub
```

Comment: `FilePath` is a variable, not a string.  Remove the double-quotes.

Comment: Also if you're looking for CSV files your extension is wrong...  See here for how to loop over all CSV files in a folder: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25163369/open-csv-file-with-excel-vba?rq=1

Comment: 1. Use `FileMonth = Format(Date, "mmmm")` to get the full month name. 2. Use `Debug.Print FilePath` before you try to open the CSV and look in hte VBE's Immediate window to make sure it is correct. 3. As above.

Comment: Oops.  was in a rush.  had several versions I was tinkering with and then copied the oldest here.  Obviously it should be ".csv"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you really understand how a variable works as you keep putting it in a string.  If you put something in double quotes it creates a string. Below is how you can add the month to the string via the variable.

```
Sub OpenCSVs()
Dim MyFiles As String, ThisMonth As String
Dim startPath As String
ThisMonth = Format(Date, "mmmm")
startPath = "C:\Users\ME\Desktop\CSV find convert tests\" & ThisMonth & "\"
MyFiles = Dir(startPath & "*.csv")

Do While MyFiles <> ""

Workbooks.Open startPath & MyFiles

       'Do stuff to it will go here
'ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True (Deactivated for now)

MyFiles = Dir

Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Oh I see... thanks so much.  The above worked perfectly.

Comment: so I recorded a Macro to parse out the CSV data.  I'm trying to save the file and convert it to xlsx format.  I want to preserve the CSV file name which was simply a date.  I found all sorts of stuff on line but none seems to work.  rec. Macro sets the file name.

Comment: Convert = Dir(startPath & "*.xlsx") 'FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False

    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs startPath & Convert
Not working. . . .:/

Comment: @ScottH I would create a new question and post the code portion there so not to get the two issues confused in case someone comes here to review this one.